# Login cookies are not set

Tags: cookies, stack, session-cookies, svelte

I recently updated my Heroku stack from 18 to 20 and suddenly my login stopped working.

Everything works fine locally, API responds to login request and sends session cookie that the browser saves, but when I upload app to Heroku, I'm suddenly no longer able to stay logged in.

No cookie is saved on my browser, but on the API side everything seems to be working.
User is serialized according to logs.

Backend is a NodeJS / Express API with Passport local login, and front end is a Svelte/Sapper app.

Everything worked fine before updating the stack

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.